# Create pdf from C#, and write to it some Persian Text does not work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I am going to convert from c# to PDF and write some Persian paragraphs to the PDF and my code is:

```
private void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Document doc = new Document();

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create));

    BaseFont persianBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Images\\IranNastaliq.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font persianFont = new Font(persianBaseFont, 12);

    Paragraph persianParagraph = new Paragraph("این یک متن فارسی است", persianFont);
    persianParagraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

    doc.Open();
    doc.Add(persianParagraph);
    doc.Close();
    Process.Start("output.pdf");
}
```

I use iTextSharp my code successfully works and, when I click the button it opens a PDF file for me but it does not support the Persian language, it shows the Persian letters separately instead of showing them in the correct way. However, I use different Persian fonts like B-Nazanin and others but it does not solve my problems. For the English language, it works and does not cause any problems but for Persian, it does not show the text correctly and shows the text like the image below:
[image]

can anyone help me to solve this issue???

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommendation, i would use Spire.PDF for .NET to achieve what you want:

```
using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Graphics;
using System.Drawing;

namespace CreatePdfDocument
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a PdfDocument object
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            //Add a page
            PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(35f));

            //Specify heading text
            String titleText = "What is MySQL";

            //Create solid brushes
            PdfSolidBrush titleBrush = new PdfSolidBrush(new PdfRGBColor(Color.Blue));
            PdfSolidBrush paraBrush = new PdfSolidBrush(new PdfRGBColor(Color.Black));

            //Create true type fonts
            PdfTrueTypeFont titleFont = new PdfTrueTypeFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 18f, FontStyle.Bold),true); 
            PdfTrueTypeFont paraFont = new PdfTrueTypeFont(new Font("Times New Roman", 12f, FontStyle.Regular), true);

            //Set the text alignment via PdfStringFormat class
            PdfStringFormat format = new PdfStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = PdfTextAlignment.Center;

            //Draw heading on the center of the page
            page.Canvas.DrawString(titleText, titleFont, titleBrush, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, 20, format);

            //Get paragraph content from a .txt file
            string paraText = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\content.txt");

            //Create a PdfTextWidget object to hold the paragrah content
            PdfTextWidget widget = new PdfTextWidget(paraText, paraFont, paraBrush);

            //Create a rectangle where the paragraph content will be placed
            RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0, 50, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Height);

            //Set the PdfLayoutType to Paginate to make the content paginated automatically
            PdfTextLayout layout = new PdfTextLayout();
            layout.Layout = PdfLayoutType.Paginate;

            //Draw the widget on the page
            widget.Draw(page, rect, layout);

            //Save to file
            doc.SaveToFile("CreatePdfDocument.pdf");
            doc.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

To view the full technical blog post follow [this link](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/NET/Spire.PDF-for-.NET/Program-Guide/Document-Operation/C-/VB.NET-Create-a-PDF-Document.html).
If you have any additional questions please feel free to ask.